# Sorting Objective-C arrays in place

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Sorting arrays in place is commonplace in object oriented programming. But that does not seem to be the default in Objective-C. In Objective-C it seems that whether I am using NSArray or NSMutableArray I can't sort in place, but rather I have to sort to a different array: i.e. another memory block. Is this really correct?

```
NSArray *germanMakes = @[@"Mercedes-Benz", @"BMW", @"Porsche",
                         @"Opel", @"Volkswagen", @"Audi"];
NSArray *sortedMakes = [germanMakes sortedArrayUsingComparator:
    ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        if ([obj1 length] < [obj2 length]) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else if ([obj1 length] > [obj2 length]) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        } else {
            return NSOrderedSame;
        }
}];
NSLog(@"%@", sortedMakes);
```

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding of my question: my problem is not sorting, obviously: my very OP includes a sorting example. I want to know how I might sort in place if that's possible.

Comment: No, only one person was confused and that answer is now deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sortedArrayUsingComparator` method returns a new array (see the docs). This is required with `NSArray` since `NSArray` is immutable.

`NSMutableArray` can be sorted in place using `sortUsingComparator`.

Of course you can simply do:

```
germanMakes = [germanMakes sortedArrayUsingComparator:...
```

For a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *someMutableArray = ... // some mutable array
[someMutableArray sortUsingComparator... // sort in place
```

Comment: What if I were to do `[germanMakes sortedArrayUsingComparator:...` and then go on to use `germanMakes`. Notice I leave out the assignment. Would `germanMakes` behave as sorted?

Comment: No, as I said, `NSArray` is immutable and `sortedArrayUsingComparator` returns a new array. Again, read the docs for those methods.

Comment: Do you mind showing a snippet where the NSMutableArray is sorted in place?

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much for persisting. +1 as well.